# Opera css bug, web app is displayed incorrectly

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, opera

I've found out that my web app is displayed incorrectly
in Opera because of the following bug:

```
#one {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
#two {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

and html:

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

instead of occupying the whole view port #two is cut by #one in Opera.
Is there a way to workaround this not affecting other browsers?

Comment: Should it not work like that? It **is** contained within `#one` which has `overflow: hidden`. If they had `position: absolute`, it would work the same way. On most browsers. (I remember that earlier versions of something had a bug which still displayed the overflowing content).

Comment: For position absolute - yes, for position fixed - no. And that's why all other major browsers (Chrome, FF, IE) expand #two on the whole screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug is fixed in Opera 11.60, it now behaves exactly like other browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/KPeYx/

Answer (score -1):

Use the read-only selector to target Opera:

```
#one:read-only { overflow: auto; }
```